# Django issue linking to static files

Tags: django, static, filepath

I'm having a lot of trouble with what I assume is a pretty simple problem, but I just can't figure it out. Right now my directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── css
│   └── registration.css
├── images
│   └── icon.png
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── registration
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── loading_page.html
│   ├── views.py
├── settings.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── registration.css
│   └── images
│       └── icon.png
├── test.txt
└── urls.py
```

I only have a root url defined, but this is the file:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
import registration

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^$', 'registration.views.registration', name="registration")
)
```

The relevant lines of my setting and template are as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="style/css" href= "{{ STATIC_URL }}css/registration.css">

STATIC_ROOT = os.getcwd()
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.getcwd(),
)
```

Basically when I try to link to static files as shown above I get 404's. I imagine I could make url patterns for static files, but my understanding is that the staticfile handlers should take care of that. Any help will be hugely appreciated. I realize that there are a number of questions similar, but I couldn't find something that I thought matched by issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using something like this

```
import os
PROYECT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROYECT, 'static')



STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_ROOT,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but issue persists unchanged.

Comment: Try putting the `static` folder inside `registration`folder (at the same level than `templates` folder )and see what happens :D

Comment: Tried both, still no change.

Answer (score 0):

```
In your settings.py try it like this:
import os.path
CURRENT_PATH=os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__).decode('utf-8')).replace('\\','/')   
STATIC_URL ='/static/'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (

os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'static').replace('\\','/'),
```

)
    in your template :
    take out the css directory and type directly
    
    it should works !!!

Comment: i forgot this in your INSTALLED_APPS =('django.contrib.staticfiles',) Make sure you add it

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.abspath('./static/')
)
```